# Passing AgGrid context from a functional React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, ag-grid

I have a component that displays a table using AgGrid, and the data that is displayed comes from a Redux selector.

I want to render a cell in the table that has a button, which will then perform an action based on the row data.

The primary issue I have, is that when I pass a callback function to the button in the cell renderer, the row data is not populated when it gets called in the parent component. I *believe* that I need to pass the proper context to the cell renderer so that when it calls the function from the parent component, all of the data is present. However, please correct me if this is incorrect. However, I'm not sure how to properly pass the context given that all of this is happening from a functional component.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-redux-context-y49fd

Click on the "Set Row Data" button, which will make the button in the rows appear. Clicking the button will then print out the row data, which will be empty.

I need a way to be able to access the row data from the cell renderer.

Answer (score 1):

**Dirty solution**

Try to bind `this` to onExecute when you are setting it to the cell render params:

```js
cellRendererParams: { onExecute: onExecute.bind(this) }
```

---

Do you need to access data of **all rows**, or only **single row** that the current cell render is rendering? If you need data of the current row only, the AgGrid has already it in props, you can acces it in `this.props.data` in your cell renderer component.

Comment: The `bind` solution unfortunately didn't work because it's from inside a functional component, and an error saying that it's the global `this` that gets captured in `() => {}` these components, however I did only need a single row, so I was able to just use it from props.

Comment: Yes, because of that I labeled it as "dirty solution". But it works in the sandbox you posted.